# jQuery Append removing/hiding previous object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not 100% sure exactly whats happening  here, but what i want to happen is for a div to be randomly added at either 50% or 25% width but one the combined length of the divs reach above 75% or 100% whilst using data attributes to add the total size of the divs together. At 75%, a 25% div is hardcoded in and the cycle starts again after the total length variable is set to 0, at 100% the total length variable is set to 0 and the randomness starts again but the divs that have been appended should exist, my problem is they don't.

For example if i get two 50% divs in a row only 1 shows, when i `console.log` the event it displays the correct numbers 50 then 100... but only 1 div is shown by append.

Hopefully my fiddle can shed some light on the situation: https://jsfiddle.net/g8urnar3/2/

(Click on the anchor tag named button to replicate the error)

My question is, whats causing this to happen and why?

As requested the code...

```
<html>
<style>
    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html, body{
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
    }
    a {
        padding: 15px;
        background: lightgrey;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .list {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: none;
    }
    a:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    div {
        height: 100px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }
    .div-50{
        width: 50%;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .div-25{
        width: 25%;
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>

<center>
    <a href="#">Button</a>
</center>

<br><br>

<hr>
<div class="list">
</div>

</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(){

        var currentLength = 0;

        var arr = [$("<div class='div-50' data-width='50'></div>"), $("<div class='div-25' data-width='25'></div>")];

        $('a').click(function(){
            console.log(currentLength);
            if(currentLength < 75)
            {
                var random = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
                currentLength = currentLength + Number($(random).attr("data-width"));
                $('.list').append(random);

                console.log(random);
                console.log($("<div class='div-25' data-width='25'></div>"));
            }
            else if(currentLength == 100) {
                currentLength = 0;
                var random = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
                currentLength = currentLength + Number($(random).attr("data-width"));
                $('.list').append(random);
            }
            else {
                currentLength = 0;
                $('.list').append($("<div class='div-25'></div>"));
                currentLength = currentLength + 25;
            }

        })

    })();
</script>
```

Comment: please post the code inline as text. The jsfiddle is a plus.

Comment: @LelioFaieta added as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your array to be:

```
var arr = ["<div class='div-50' data-width='50'></div>", "<div class='div-25' data-width='25'></div>"];
```

Comment: This has solved it, can i ask if you know why adding them as a jquery object causes this behaviour?

Comment: It would be fine with jquery object, but the selector you used is invalid really, here's link about selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/   HTML is not a valid selector, you could use javascript's getElementById to get existing element and convert that to jQuery with $(element), but that's different. I'm surprised it worked to the extent it did.

Comment: no actually that makes sense now that i look over the code again, I think what was misleading was that it works at all. I guess sometimes something working can be the biggest error of all#